# save changes in datagrid to dataset

Tags: c#

I get data from database like this(dataset - ShoppingMallDataSet(smds)).

```
private void Clients()
    {
        using (ShoppingMallDataSetTableAdapters.TClientTableAdapter tcta =
               new ShoppingMallDataSetTableAdapters.TClientTableAdapter() { Connection = new SqlConnection(connection_string) })
        {
            tcta.Fill(smds.TClient);
            for (int i = 0; i < smds.TClient.Columns.Count; i++)
                if (smds.TClient.Columns[i].ColumnName.Substring(0, 2).Equals("id"))
                    smds.TClient.Columns[i].ReadOnly = false;
            bs.DataSource = smds.TClient;
        }
    }
```

where bs - BindingSource. For datagrid I set binding source as datasource `rgv.DataSource = bs;`. When I make some changes I want to save it to database. So I've created a button and button click event

```
void rb1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        smds.AcceptChanges();
    }
```

But it doesn't save changes. 
What I need to add or to change?

Comment: you are updating dataset not the database.. after updating dataset write the dataset to database. what is your database here? if it is xml, do `smds.WriteXml(filepath)`.

Comment: my database - ShoppingMall.mdf. I've added dataset as `add new data source`